# TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'nullable'

Tags: python-3.x, database, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently working on my flask app, its a application for book repository for final year students, where they can upload their final year projects and other relevant books for other students, so i was setting up my database and i encountered this error message here. I am new to programming and this is my first project.

```
v) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub>python
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from eduhub import db
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:833: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS 
adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\eduhub.py", line 58, in <module>
    class Project(db.Model):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 67, in __init__
    super(NameMetaMixin, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 121, in __init__
    super(BindMetaMixin, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\api.py", line 76, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 131, in _as_declarative
    _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(cls, classname, dict_)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 160, in setup_mapping
    cfg_cls(cls_, classname, dict_)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 190, in __init__
    self._setup_table()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 534, in _setup_table
    cls.__table__ = table = table_cls(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 99, in __table_cls__
    return sa.Table(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 139, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 560, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 555, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 654, in _init
    self._init_items(*args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 118, in _init_items
    spwd(self)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 464, in _set_parent_with_dispatch
    self.dispatch.after_parent_attach(self, parent)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", line 322, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 2199, in _set_table
    self.constraint = ForeignKeyConstraint(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3324, in __init__
    Constraint.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 2890, in __init__
    self._validate_dialect_kwargs(dialect_kw)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 290, in _validate_dialect_kwargs
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'nullable'
>>> from eduhub import db
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:833: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS 
adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\eduhub.py", line 63, in <module>
    class Book(db.Model):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 67, in __init__
    super(NameMetaMixin, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 121, in __init__
    super(BindMetaMixin, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\api.py", line 76, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 131, in _as_declarative
    _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(cls, classname, dict_)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 160, in setup_mapping
    cfg_cls(cls_, classname, dict_)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 190, in __init__
    self._setup_table()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 534, in _setup_table
    cls.__table__ = table = table_cls(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 99, in __table_cls__
    return sa.Table(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 139, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 560, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 555, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 654, in _init
    self._init_items(*args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 118, in _init_items
    spwd(self)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 464, in _set_parent_with_dispatch
    self.dispatch.after_parent_attach(self, parent)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", line 322, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 2199, in _set_table
    self.constraint = ForeignKeyConstraint(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3324, in __init__
    Constraint.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 2890, in __init__
    self._validate_dialect_kwargs(dialect_kw)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\educationhub\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 290, in _validate_dialect_kwargs
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'nullable'
>>>  `

My code 

from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = ""
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)




#Users Details
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    education = db.relationship('Education', backref='author')

    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book_id'), nullable=False)
    books = db.relationship('Book', backref='author', lazy=True)

    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project_id'), nullable=False)
    projects = db.relationship('Project', backref='author', lazy=True)

    #Upload Books/Projects
    uploaded_books = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    downloaded_books = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    uploaded_projects = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    downloaded_books = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)

    #Users Personal Details
    aboutme = db.Column(db.String(450), nullable=False, default="No Description")
    phone = db.Column(db.Numeric(20, 0), nullable=False, default="00000000000")
    location = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, default="Unknown City")

    # User Image Filename
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f""""Users
        '{self.fname}', 
        '{self.lname}', 
        '{self.username}', 
        '{self.email}',
        '{self.uploaded_books}',
        '{self.downloaded_books}',
        '{self.uploaded_projects}',
        '{self.downloaded_projects}',
        '{self.image_file}'"""



#Educational Books
class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    book_title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, default="Author Name")
    isdn = db.Column(db.Numeric(20, 0), unique=True, nullable=False, default="0000000000000")
    filename = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default="default.pdf")
    image = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    book_description = db.Column(db.String(400), nullable=False, default="About Book")
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', nullable=False))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""Book
        '{self.book_title}', 
        '{self.author}',
        '{self.isdn}',
        '{self.filename}',
        '{self.image}',
        '{self.date_posted}', 
        '{self.book_description}'"""




#Final Year Projects
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    project_title = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    project_author = db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False,default="Written By")
    filename = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default="default.pdf")
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=datatime.utcnow)
    project_description = db.Column(db.String(400),nullable=False,default="About Project")
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', nullable=False))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""Project
        '{self.project_title}', 
        '{self.project_author}', 
        '{self.filename}',
        '{self.date_posted},'
        '{self.project_description}'"""



#Edcational Qualification
class Education(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    school = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    institution = db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False,default="University")
    course = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, default="Economics")
    fromDate = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=True)
    toDate = db.Column(db.Numeric(5, 0), nullable=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(160), nullable=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', nullable=False))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""Education
        '{self.school}', 
        '{self.institution}', 
        '{self.course}', 
        '{self.fromDate}', 
        '{self.toDate}', 
        '{self.description}'"""


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")


@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f"Account created for { form.username.data }!" "success")
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    return render_template("register.html", title="Register", form=form)


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == "admin@blog.com" and form.password.data == "password":
            flash("You have been logged in!", "success")
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
        else:
            flash("Login Unsucessful. Please Check username and password",
                  "danger")
    return render_template("login.html", title="Login", form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: you're missing a ```)``` in ```user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', nullable=False))```  and other lines like it

Comment: Thanks, i was able to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

They is a typo from user_id

**Typo**

```
 user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', nullable=False))
```

**correction**

```
 user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```